# Publishing executables and websites with NuGet

Tags: asp.net, .net, packaging, nuget

I'm looking to standardize our publishing mechanism for libraries, executables and websites.

All the documentation on the NuGet website talks about publishing libraries, tools and source files but there does not seem to be any guidance on the directory structure when publishing fully packaged executables and websites.

Is there any guidance or existing convention on this?

If I were to make something up it would look like:

```
exe/net40/*.*
website/net40/**/*.*
```

Comment: Chocolatey - http://chocolatey.org

Answer (score 11):

We are using [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation) by Paul Stovell, an automated deployment tool which pulls from a Nuget feed and distributes your application using a central dashboard.

We also have some msbuild scripts following the conventions on his site which tell you [how to build  the nuget files](http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation/packaging).

Apparently, the latest version of [Teamcity (EAP) can automatically package](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/08/native-nuget-support-in-teamcity/) your artifacts to nuget packages and [act as a NuGet server](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2011/12/01/setting-up-teamcity-as-a-native-nuget-server/).

We have had much success using both TC and Octopus Deploy for automated build and deployment.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I just added a few more relevant links to the body

Answer (score 8):

NuGet was not meant for tools/applications/executables. It is meant for things that go into the source and working with the source.  Where NuGet stops, [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org) comes in. You can also use Octopus for conventional deployment, see [the answer in this question with Octopus Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9036221/18475). You can also integrate Chocolatey with Octopus.

Chocolatey will have better support for packaging up websites and getting them installed as websites in the future. At the time of this answer it doesn't yet have a built in function for installing a web application.

Comment: any update on the status of deploying websites with Chocolatey?

Comment: @DavidCumps You can definitely do it with powershell and Pro Get has it built in now, but core chocolatey doesn't yet have any helper functions that make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

I've been preparing the Nuget setup in our company for distributing our libraries to our developers.

The thing with Nuget is, you can do a lot of things, but is it worth the effort to make it do something it not really intended for.

Seems easier to use other software like CruiseControl or something similar to distribute finished programs and websites.

Most of the custom things you can do with Nuget, can only be used inside Visual Studio.

May be you can also look at Chocolatey ( an adaption for Nuget for installing Applications)